# Invalid state, the ResultSet object is closed

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am running the code, however am getting a "Invalid state, the ResultSet object is closed." error.  What is causing the error?

```
try{
    query = "SELECT * FROM BUNDLE_TEMP "
                  + "MINUS "
                  + "SELECT * FROM BUNDLE";

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()){
                String bundle = rs.getString("BUNDLE");
                String week = rs.getString("WEEK");
                String sched_dt = rs.getString("SCHED_DT").replace(" 00:00:00.0", "");
                String dropper_id = rs.getString("DROPPER_ID");


                query = "INSERT INTO BUNDLE "
                            + "VALUES ('"
                                + bundle+"','"
                                + week+"','"
                                + sched_dt+"','"
                                + dropper_id+"')";

                stmt.executeUpdate(query);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error while trying to insert into BUNDLE\n"+query+"\n"+ e);
        }
```

Comment: Please post the exception stacktrace in your question, it contains valuable information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Philipp is right. I think you could even have a network outage that cuts connection between the two queries, and the problem could give the same message you showed us.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot execute another SQL query on the same `Statement` you're currently iterating over with a `ResultSet`. Doing this will close the previously open cursor (your `SELECT` query resp. `ResultSet`):

To quote the [API docs for Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.

Create another `Statement` instance from your `Connection`, let's call it `updateStmt` and `executeUpdate()` on that one.

Also, look into [Prepared Statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for your update, it will probably be more performant and secure.